# How do I customize the generated index page in Docusaurus?

Tags: docusaurus

I have a generated-index page, and I can see how to customize the on-page title and description in the *category*.json for the directory, but is there a way to customize the items generated by the files in the same directory? For example:

- tutorials

  - _category_.json
  - 01-first-tutorial.md
  - 02-second-tutorial.md

I want to be able to have an icon for each of the files and different text than what is pulled from those files first paragraph like seems to be the default. What I want perhaps looks something like [this page](https://docusaurus-mdx-2.vercel.app/), but the icons and text need to be linked to the tutorial pages.

I have tried using a DocCardList, adding in descriptions, adding in items (failed), and changing each of my tutorial files, but so far, no love.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT:**

They've come up with a new component called [DocCardList](https://docusaurus.io/docs/sidebar/items#embedding-generated-index-in-doc-page) which you can use in version 2.3.0.

1. Create an `index.mdx` file in your category folder.
2. Add the following:

   ```
   import DocCardList from '@theme/DocCardList';

   <DocCardList />
   ```
3. Swizzle or otherwise override this component in your `src/theme` folder to add custom styling, etc.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

Maybe you could try swapping the generated index component using the `docCategoryGeneratedIndexComponent` prop ([link to reference](https://docusaurus.io/docs/api/plugins/@docusaurus/plugin-content-docs#docCategoryGeneratedIndexComponent)). That would replace all auto-generated index pages which might be what you want.

In `docusaurus.config.js`, in the `presets` section, add

```
presets: [
    [
      "classic",
      /** @type {import('@docusaurus/preset-classic').Options} */
      ({
        docs: {
          sidebarPath: require.resolve("./sidebars.js"),
          docCategoryGeneratedIndexComponent:
            "@site/src/components/CategoryIndexPage",
        },
        // etc.
      }),
    ],
  ],
```

And then try adding the following custom component under `src/components/CategoryIndexPage.tsx`:

```
import React from "react";

export default function CategoryIndexPage(props) {
  return (
    <pre>
      <code>{JSON.stringify(props, null, 2)}</code>
    </pre>
  );
}
```

This will just show you what the prop structure is in the component.

When I looked in the theme component which generates this page, it uses

```
const category = useCurrentSidebarCategory();
```

But when I try that to get the list of items, I get the following error:

> Hook useDocsSidebar is called outside the .

Maybe you can figure out the next steps, I was not able to.

Alternatively, you can create an `index.mdx` file in your category folder and import a custom React component into that. That gives me the same context violation error, though.

```
# My custom category page

Some Markdown content here.

import CategoryIndex from "@site/src/components/CategoryIndex.tsx";

<CategoryIndex />
```

Comment: I saw the DocCardList, but what I cannot figure out is how you customize the text and image inside each of the rectangles.

Comment: If you put a file called `DocCardList.tsx` in your `src/theme` folder, you can implement it however you want. So change test, dd images, etc. Look inside `node_modules/@docusaurus/theme-classic/src/theme/DocCardList/index.tsx` to see how they did is and try playing around with it.

Answer (score 2):

You can add class to `DocCardList` and then customize styles in custom css.

In your `mdx` doc:

```
<DocCardList className="DocCardList--no-description" />
```

In `src/css/custom.css`:

```css
.DocCardList--no-description .card h2 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.DocCardList--no-description .card p {
  display: none;
}
```

Though, if you need to customize logic then you have to do like [@pawel-kowaluk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3778721/pawel-kowaluk) suggested in the comments in the answer above.